# JavaScript Onclick Not Working on First Click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a program that has calendar popups and text input fields. When the user clicks on the text input field I am doing an onclick to check whether the value of the calendar field is not zero. If it is the input field sets `readonly` to false.

My onclick function only works after the user click on the text input twice after the page loads. I need this code to work on the first click and each click past that. After a few tests this problem only occurs in Internet Explorer.

The code I am using is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<title>t</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/websmart/v5/javascript/imgswap.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/websmart/v5/javascript/mm_menu.js"></script>
 <link rel="StyleSheet" href="/websmart/v5/stylesheets/birdseyeblue.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/stars/html/CalendarPopup.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">document.write(CalendarPopup_getStyles());</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CheckVal = function (fieldNum)
{
    var str = 'BQXAWDDT'+fieldNum;
    var str2 = 'BQXGNB'+fieldNum;
    var DVal = document.getElementById(str).value;

    if(DVal == "00/00/0000")
    {
        document.getElementById(str2).readOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(str2).readOnly = false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<P>
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
            <TR>
                <TD WIDTH="100"><IMG SRC="/Stars/HTML/STAC001/left_image.jpg" WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="50" ALIGN="BOTTOM" BORDER="0"></TD>
                <TD WIDTH="100%"><IMG SRC="/Stars/HTML/STAC001/center.jpg" ALIGN="BOTTOM" BORDER="0"></TD>
                <TD WIDTH="400"><IMG SRC="/Stars/HTML/STAC001/right_image.jpg" ALIGN="BOTTOM" BORDER="0"></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
            <TR>
                <TD HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#6392C6">
                <P ALIGN="CENTER">
<font color=red>**Test**</font>                 </td>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<B><font color="#CC0000">Update Source Details</font></b>
<br>
<form action="PATUPD.pgm" id="PATUPDADD" name="PATUPDADD" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="endupd">
<input type="hidden" name="SelComp" value="STAC">
<input type="hidden" name="SelSchool" value="001">
<input type="hidden" name="SelStudent" value="0000000033">
<input type="hidden" name="SelSource" value="AppFee">
<input type="hidden" name="SelYear" value="2012">
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="text"><b>Student #:&nbsp;33&nbsp;&nbsp;Robert&nbsp;Amell</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text"><b>Source Code:&nbsp;AppFee&nbsp;&nbsp;Application Fee Payment</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="bar">
<th style="display:none;"></th>

    <td valign="top" width="40">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="bar"> 
            <td width="10%" align="left" valign="top"><img src="/websmart/v5/tpli/birdseyeblue/corner_left.gif" width="11" height="20"></td>
            <td width="90%">Date</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="100" class="text2" valign="top">Projected Amount</td>

    <td valign="top">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="bar"> 
            <td width="90%">Actual Amount</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right" valign="top"><img src="/websmart/v5/tpli/birdseyeblue/corner_right.gif" width="11" height="20"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002905">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT1" id="BQXAWDDT1" value="01/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT1,'anchor01','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor01" ID="anchor01"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB1" onclick="CheckVal(1); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=12.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
   </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002906">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT2" id="BQXAWDDT2" value="02/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT2,'anchor02','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor02" ID="anchor02"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB2" onclick="CheckVal(2); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=1233.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
  </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002907">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT3" id="BQXAWDDT3" value="03/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT3,'anchor03','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor03" ID="anchor03"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB3" onclick="CheckVal(3); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=123.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
 </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000052275">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT4" id="BQXAWDDT4" value="03/08/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT4,'anchor04','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor04" ID="anchor04"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB4" onclick="CheckVal(4); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=1000.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
  </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002908">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT5" id="BQXAWDDT5" value="04/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT5,'anchor05','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor05" ID="anchor05"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB5" onclick="CheckVal(5); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=234.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
   </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002909">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT6" id="BQXAWDDT6" value="04/03/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT6,'anchor06','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor06" ID="anchor06"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB6" onclick="CheckVal(6); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
  </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000052276">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT7" id="BQXAWDDT7" value="05/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT7,'anchor07','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor07" ID="anchor07"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB7" onclick="CheckVal(7); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
     </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002910">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT8" id="BQXAWDDT8" value="06/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT8,'anchor08','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor08" ID="anchor08"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB8" onclick="CheckVal(8); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=14.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002911">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT9" id="BQXAWDDT9" value="07/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT9,'anchor09','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor09" ID="anchor09"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB9" onclick="CheckVal(9); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=41.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002912">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT10" id="BQXAWDDT10" value="08/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT10,'anchor10','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor10" ID="anchor10"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB10" onclick="CheckVal(10); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=51.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
   </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002913">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT11" id="BQXAWDDT11" value="09/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT11,'anchor11','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor11" ID="anchor11"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB11" onclick="CheckVal(11); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=15.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002914">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT12" id="BQXAWDDT12" value="10/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT12,'anchor12','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor12" ID="anchor12"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB12" onclick="CheckVal(12); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=51.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002915">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT13" id="BQXAWDDT13" value="11/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT13,'anchor13','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor13" ID="anchor13"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB13" onclick="CheckVal(13); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=61.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000002916">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT14" id="BQXAWDDT14" value="12/01/2012" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT14,'anchor14','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor14" ID="anchor14"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB14" onclick="CheckVal(14); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9"  value=133.00></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000000000">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT15" id="BQXAWDDT15" value="00/00/0000" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT15,'anchor15','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor15" ID="anchor15"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB15" onclick="CheckVal(15); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9" readonly value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
     </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000000000">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT16" id="BQXAWDDT16" value="00/00/0000" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT16,'anchor16','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor16" ID="anchor16"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB16" onclick="CheckVal(16); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9" readonly value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000000000">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT17" id="BQXAWDDT17" value="00/00/0000" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT17,'anchor17','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor17" ID="anchor17"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB17" onclick="CheckVal(17); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9" readonly value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<input type="hidden" name="Detrrn" value="000000000">
<td width="150" class="text"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">var cal1 = new CalendarPopup();</SCRIPT>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" READONLY NAME="BQXAWDDT18" id="BQXAWDDT18" value="00/00/0000" SIZE=10> 
        <A HREF="#" onClick="cal1.select(document.forms[0].BQXAWDDT18,'anchor18','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" NAME="anchor18" ID="anchor18"><img src="/stars/html/calbtn.gif" border="0" height="21" width="34" align="absmiddle"></A></td>
<td width="70"><input type="textN" name="BQXGNB" id="BQXGNB18" onclick="CheckVal(18); return false;" size="9" maxlength="9" readonly value=></td>
<td width="90" class="textN"></td>
 </tr><input type="hidden" name="rcdcnt" value="18">
 </table>
 <br>

 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Update">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location='PATUPD.pgm?Task=DEFAULT&SelComp=STAC&SelSchool=001&SelStudent=0000000033&SelSource=AppFee&Page=00000&rnd=38821&SelYear=2012'">
 </form>
 <P>
 <TABLE ALIGN="CENTER" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="80">
 <TR>
 </TR>
  <TR>
 <TD WIDTH="80"  ALIGN="CENTER"><IMG SRC="/htdocs/STARS.gif" WIDTH="80" HEIGHT="30" P ALIGN="CENTER"></TD>
  </TR>
  </P>
        
                

  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what a mess. make the code simpler :/

Comment: @AamirAfridi: Looks auto-generated from a template to me.

Comment: I think your problem might be a feature, not a bug. When you click it, it changes the `readonly` attributes, but it simply doesn't give the focus back to the field. I don't make this an answer cause your question is too vague to be sure that's your problem.

Comment: Why do you have an HTML comment block starting before your function in your javascript tag? Then the closing is commented out... `<!--` and `// -->`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aelor/8aVhy/ haha no need to thank its okay

Comment: @aelor Did you make changes to my code or just present it pretty?

Comment: i didnt make any changes to your code. i made a fiddle so that its easier for others to work upon that. Now you can explain what problem you are having

Comment: This code should work everytime the user clicks the input field but the problem I am having is the user must click on the field twice after page loads to get the code working.

Comment: Looks like it works fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/UGqrv/ I pick a date on the dropdown and change it from 00/00/0000 and then click the input text field and it turns off readonly.

Comment: @Chad where can you see the dropdown sir ?

Comment: @aelor Sorry, it's a small popup not a dropdown. It opens if you click the broken image icon between the date field and the input field.

Comment: lol i couldnt see it, its visible only in chrome not in firefox